# Why does my p-element follow immediately after the last without a break in between?

Tags: html, css

I have in my database something stored as `<p>Some words.</p><p>Some more words.</p>` but this gives me some problems when I'm trying to fit an icon onto the same line as the first `p`.

I tried this solution:

```
<i class="icon"></i>
<div class="words">
    <p>Some words.</p>
    <p>Some more words.</p>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.words {
    display: inline;
}

.words p:first-child {
    display: inline;
}
```

However, this makes the `p` that in my example says `Some more words` show up immediately after the last line without a break in between.

The weird thing is that I can't reproduce this in jsfiddle, so there has to be some other css from my page messing things up, but I haven't managed to find it despite unclicking every property inside Inspect Element.

I want the text to show up like this:

```
Some words.

Some more words.
```

NOT like this:

```
Some words.
Some more words.
```

Does anyone have a guess as why this doesn't work, or know how I can force the `p` after the first one to make a break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your `p` elements are being separated by only a bottom margin, and not a top margin. [An inline element doesn't have top and bottom margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties), so when you set the first `p` element to inline, it loses its bottom margin, and its sibling doesn't have a top margin to keep it from shifting upward. So the simplest workaround is to give its sibling a top margin:

```
.words {
    display: inline;
}

.words p:first-child {
    display: inline;
}

.words p:first-child + p {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

In most default stylesheets, which an empty fiddle usually starts out with, `p` elements have both top and bottom margins (which collapse, meaning removing one's bottom margin still leaves the other's top margin occupying the same amount of space).

FWIW, although your parent element is set to display inline as well (to align the first line of text with the icon), that shouldn't affect how margins are calculated between its block-level contents. In fact, displaying a parent element inline has [*no* adverse effects on the layout of its block-level contents](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level).

Answer (score -1):

the following will do

```
.words p{
    margin:0;
}
```